# Is Miller-Rabin not a suitable algortihm for the RSA key generation or am I missing something?

Tags: algorithms, cryptography, primes

I'm trying to recreate the RSA key generator, from what I understood you must create two prime numbers of 256 bytes long, `p` and `q`. Since there really isn't a method able to generate prime numbers, you must generate random numbers so then you can test their primality using an algorithm.

Here is where the [Rabin-Miller's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) comes in proposing `a^d mod n` in order to test the primality of a number: (From here I'm merely trying to understand if I'm missing something)

`n` is the number being tested (either `q` or `p`)

The value of `a` is any number between 2 and `n-2`.

The value of `d` is the largest power of 2 that divides `n-1`

Then just raise `a` to the power of `d` and put the result into *modulus operation* with `n` (`a^d % n`)

If I so far my procedure has been correct explain me how does RSA manage not to overflow while `a`^`d` if those numbers are often too long, also I'd like to know if at some point of the procedure I made a mistake.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation